# VSCodeの編集画面で右クリックメニューを変更したい

Tags: vscode

VSCodeの編集画面で右クリックしたときのコンテキストメニューを編集することはできますか。
例えば単語を選択したときに大文字や小文字に変更したりとか、複数行選択したときにソートするとか。

### 追記

コメントで提示されたurlを参考にいろいろ試しているのですがどうもうまくいきません。
これらは新規に拡張機能を作成するということなんでしょうか?
自身で作成したcolor-themeのpackage.jsonに"menus"を追加してみましたが表示できませんでした。

```js
{
    "name": "theme-slateblue",
    "displayName": "%displayName%",
    "description": "%description%",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "engines": { "vscode": "*" },
    "contributes": {
        "themes": [
            {
                "label": "Slateblue",
                "uiTheme": "vs-dark",
                "path": "./themes/slateblue-color-theme.json"
            }
        ],
        "menus": {
            "editor/context": [{
                "when": "editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus",
                "command": "editor.action.transformToLowercase",
                "group": "modification"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

このような方法ではだめなのでしょうか。
何か間違いがあると思うのですが、ご指摘いただければ幸いです。

Comment: この辺の記事を読み解くと何か出来そうです。[VSCode拡張機能開発でコンテキストメニューを使う](https://qiita.com/shyne/items/1e625baf1dff74624838), [contributes.menus](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus), [How to customize context menu in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46714353/9014308), [How to add context menu with VSCode extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41400280/9014308)

Comment: 何をどうしようとしたか、結果がどうなって何が足りていないか、といったことを整理して質問に追記すると、何か助言が得られるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コマンドは`commands`セクションで宣言する必要があります。`package.json`の`contributes`以下に次のように追記してみてください。

```
"commands": [
  {
    "command": "editor.action.transformToLowercase",
    "title": "To lowercase"
  }
],
```

ちなみに(VSCodeで)`editor/context`以下の`command`の部分にマウスオーバーするとこれについてのヘルプが表示されました。

Comment: ご指摘通り追加したらできました!! vvv^^vvv